# Symfony 2, strange error with starting server

Tags: php, xml, symfony

I have a little problem with Symfony 2. Now, when I try to launch the server pops up the following error. From what I read is associated with the file service.xml. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

File service.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services
                        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <parameters>
        <parameter key="rest_demo.note.handler.class">
            Rest\DemoBundle\Handler\NoteHandler
        </parameter>
        <parameter key="rest_demo.note.class">
            Rest\DemoBundle\Entity\Note</parameter>
    </parameters>

    <services>
        <service id="rest_demo.note.handler" class="%rest_demo.note.handler.class%">
            <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
            <argument>%rest_demo.note.class%</argument>
            <argument type="service" id="form.factory"></argument>
        </service>
    </services>

</container>
```

Error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]  
  "'                                                                          
              Rest\\DemoBundle\\Handler\\NoteHandler                          
          '" is not a valid class name for the "rest_demo.note.handle         
  r" service.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xml` config doesn't work with whitespace, you should write your config without empty spaces, like this:

```
<parameter key="rest_demo.note.handler.class">Rest\DemoBundle\Handler\NoteHandler</parameter>
```

From the [doc page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html#parameters-in-configuration-files):

> The values between parameter tags in XML configuration files are not
>   trimmed. This means that the following configuration sample will have
>   the value \n sendmail\n:
>
> ```
> <parameter key="mailer.transport">
>     sendmail
> </parameter>
> ```
>
> In some cases (for constants or class names), this could throw errors.
>   In order to prevent this, you must always inline your parameters as
>   follow:
>
> ```
> <parameter key="mailer.transport">sendmail</parameter>
> ```